# How to add a binary data file in the same directory as of exe using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, compilation, binary, pyinstaller

I have a binary text file which I want to embed in `--onefile` using pyinstaller.
The text file should be in the same directory as of the program.
I used `pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary a.txt;. A.py` but it creates an error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Appdata\Local\pyinstaller\bin000cache\a.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running as admin, the file doesnt let the executable access it....
optionally you can create a py script out of the file from another py script, and have this script just store the binary data as a variable, it would arugably be the same size as the text file, but i wouldnt open the script in an editor

```
a='txtfile="""'
with open('script.py' as 'wb') as v:
    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
         a+=f.read()
    a+="""'
    v.write(a)
```

use the var = */* something for multiple line strings
once you `import script.py`
it will read all that into memory,but u can `del script.txtfile` later

Comment: I have tried that admin method. I guess I will go for the second one

Comment: there is syntax for multiple line strings, use import to 'open the file' and then use del to 'close it'

Comment: also treating a true text file as binary is confusing, you can just read as 'r' or 'w' and then string.encode('utf-8') if u need too. else i suspect it isn't a text file really.. if binary concerns you

Comment: Actually it stores some of the variables thats why I needed binary mode